# 'LSTM' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Here is my model code:

```
encoder = Embedding(input_dim=dataset.shape[0],output_dim=300, mask_zero=True, input_length=12,embeddings_initializer='uniform')
encoder = LSTM(epochs, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True, unroll=True)
encoder_last = encoder[:,-1,:]
```

and I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-3967dfedaa44> in <module>
      1 encoder = Embedding(input_dim=dataset.shape[0],output_dim=300, mask_zero=True, input_length=12,embeddings_initializer='uniform')
      2 encoder = LSTM(epochs, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True, unroll=True)
----> 3 encoder_last = encoder[:,-1,:]

TypeError: 'LSTM' object is not subscriptable
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Its not a matter of just giving code and asking how to fix it, you have a conceptual problem, why are you subscripting (using []) on an LSTM layer object? What do you expect to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to **apply** the `LSTM` layer on the **output** of `Embedding` layer and then take the last output of LSTM. Therefore, first you need to **call (i.e. apply)** the layers you have defined on some **tensors (i.e. output of a layer)** like this:

```
inp = Input(shape=...)
encoder = Embedding(...)(inp)  # call embedding layer on inputs
encoder = LSTM(...)(encoder)   # call lstm layer on the output of embedding layer
```

This way the layers are connected to each other. Then you need to use a `Lambda` layer to slice the LSTM layer output:

```
encoder_last = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1,:])(encoder)
```